# Mysql point data type & glength returns null

Tags: mysql, sql, geospatial, spatial

The following `glength()` statement returns null always.

```
SET @mref_point1=point(12.937060,77.671280);
SET @mref_point2=point(13.937060,73.271280);

SELECT GLENGTH(LINESTRINGFROMWKB(linestring(ASBINARY(@mref_point1),ASBINARY(@mref_point2))));
```

Can someone point me in right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I post this as an answer so the code can be read more easily:

Try narrowing down the problem by these steps:

```
select ASBINARY(@mref_point1)
```

If that does not return null go ahead and do:

```
select linestring(ASBINARY(@mref_point1),ASBINARY(@mref_point2))
```

If that does not return null go ahead and do:

```
select LINESTRINGFROMWKB(linestring(ASBINARY(@mref_point1),ASBINARY(@mref_point2)))
```